# jQuery filter for cell but change backgroundcolour of row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Here is a working function for filtering cells in a datatable and change the background colour.

```
$("#AdressenTabelle tr td").filter(function() 
{
    var x = "Baum";
    return $(this).text() === x;
    }).css( "background-color", "red" );   
}
```

How could is it possible to filter for cell but change the backgroundcolour of the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$("#AdressenTabelle tr td").filter(function () {
    var x = "Baum";
    return $(this).text() === x;
}).closest('tr').css("background-color", "red");
 //^
```